# Wick contraction help

Tags: tikz-feynman

i am trying to reproduce these contractions of peskin.But none of my code works.
please help me out here.thank you.

[image: The contractions i want to reproduce]

```
 \documentclass{beamer}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{simpler-wick}
 \begin{document}
 $
  \wick{    
\langle \c1 {p'},\c2{k'}|(\c2{\Bar{\psi}}\c3\psi)_x(\c1{\Bar{\psi}}\c4\psi)_y|\c4p,\c3k \rangle
        }
 $

 $ \wick[offset=2em]{
 \langle 0|\c1 a_{k'}\c2 a_{p'}\c1 \Bar{\psi}_x \c3 \psi_x \c2 \Bar{\psi}_y \c4\psi_y \c4 a_p^{\dagger}\c3 a_k^{\dagger}|0 \rangle            }   
 $

 $
\wick[offset=2em]{

   \langle \c1 {p'}, \c2 {k'}|(\c1 {\Bar{\psi}}\c4  \psi)_x(\c2 {\Bar{\psi}}\c3 \psi)_y|\c3 p,\c4 k \rangle
                  }
 $

 $
 \wick[offset=2em]{
  \langle 0|\c1 a_{k'}\c2 a_{p'}\c2 \Bar{\psi}_x \c3 \psi_x \c1 \Bar{\psi}_y \c4\psi_y \c4 a_p^{\dagger}\c3 a_k^{\dagger}|0 \rangle
                   }
 $
 \end{document}
```

all these gives no result except this.
i dont understand why.i tried to put a curly braces after each 
\c1 but no result been produced..:(
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made your code run through, mainly by adding curly brackets.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{simpler-wick}
 \begin{document}
 $
  \wick{    
\langle \c1{p'},\c2{k'}|(\c2{\Bar{\psi}}\c3\psi)_x(\c1{\Bar{\psi}}\c4\psi)_y|\c4p,\c3k \rangle
        }
 $

 $ \wick[offset=2em]{
 \langle 0|\c1{a}_{k'}\c2{a}_{p'}\c1{\Bar{\psi}_x} \c3{\psi_x} 
 \c2{\Bar{\psi}_y}\c4{\psi_y} \c4{a_p^{\dagger}}\c3{a_k^{\dagger}}|0 \rangle            
 }  
 $

 $
\wick[offset=2em]{
   \langle \c1{p'}, \c2{k'}|(\c1{\Bar{\psi}}\c4{\psi})_x(\c2{\Bar{\psi}}
   \c3{\psi})_y|\c3{p},\c4{k}\rangle
                  }
 $

 $
 \wick[offset=2em]{
  \langle 0|\c1{a}_{k'}\c2{a}_{p'}\c2{\Bar{\psi}_x} \c3{\psi_x} 
  \c1{\Bar{\psi}_y} \c4{\psi_y} \c4{a_p^{\dagger}}\c3{a_k^{\dagger}}|0 \rangle
                   }
 $
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Do you really want to use these huge offsets?

Comment: well.thank you sir.is there a better way? how would you prefer to do this?

Comment: anyway it will work fine.but if you have some ingenious way will be happy to see that.thank you a lot.

Comment: @jowadulkader I would mainly reduce the huge offsets.

Comment: yes its clumsy.very clumsy